# Is there a more idiomatic way to keep an optional argument string from being freed?

Tags: c, rust, command-line-arguments, ffi

I want to take command-line arguments in a Rust program and pass them to a C function. However, these arguments are optional and the program should behave differently if no arguments are supplied. I have read the docs for [`CString::as_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.as_ptr) but I had hoped that keeping a local variable containing an `Option` containing the argument, (if it exists,) would keep that `String` from being freed as in the following example.

This Rust code:

```
extern crate libc;

use std::ffi::CString;

extern "C" {
    fn print_in_c(opt_class: *const libc::c_char) -> libc::c_int;
}

fn main() {
    let mut args = std::env::args();
    //skip execuatble name
    args.next();

    let possible_arg = args.next();

    println!("{:?}", possible_arg);

    let arg_ptr = match possible_arg {
        Some(arg) => CString::new(arg).unwrap().as_ptr(),

        None => std::ptr::null(),
    };

    unsafe {
        print_in_c(arg_ptr);
    };
}
```

Along with this C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int
print_in_c(const char *bar)
{
  puts("C:");
  puts(bar);

  return 0;
}
```

But this didn't work.
The code prints out the following when passed an argument of "foo":

```
Some("foo")
C:
```

Followed by a blank line.

I got the program to print the correct text if I change the Rust code to the following:

```
extern crate libc;

use std::ffi::CString;

extern "C" {
    fn print_in_c(opt_class: *const libc::c_char) -> libc::c_int;
}

fn main() {
    let mut args = std::env::args();
    //skip execuatble name
    args.next();

    let possible_arg = args.next();

    println!("{:?}", possible_arg);

    let mut might_be_necessary = CString::new("").unwrap();

    let arg_ptr = match possible_arg {
        Some(arg) => {
            might_be_necessary = CString::new(arg).unwrap();
            might_be_necessary.as_ptr()
        }

        None => std::ptr::null(),
    };

    unsafe {
        print_in_c(arg_ptr);
    };
}
```

When run, this prints

```
Some("foo")
C:
foo
```

as expected.

This method technically works, but it is awkward to extend to multiple arguments and results in a compiler warning:

```
warning: value assigned to `might_be_necessary` is never read
  --> src/main.rs:19:9
   |
19 |     let mut might_be_necessary = CString::new("").unwrap();
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: #[warn(unused_assignments)] on by default
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that your code is creating a temporary `CString` but holding on to just a pointer. The actual `CString` is dropped, while the dangling pointer is passed to the C function. To understand what's going on, it is useful to expand the pattern match to a more verbose form:

```
let arg_ptr = match possible_arg {
    Some(arg) => {
        let tmp = CString::new(arg).unwrap();
        tmp.as_ptr()
    } // <-- tmp gets destructed here, arg_ptr is dangling
    None => std::ptr::null(),
};
```

Safe Rust prevents dangling pointers by only supporting pointer indirection through *references*, whose lifetimes are carefully tracked by the compiler. Any use of a reference that outlives the object is automatically rejected at compile time. But you are using raw pointers and an `unsafe` block which prevents those checks from taking place, so you need to manually ensure proper lifetimes. And indeed, the second snippet fixes the problem by creating a local variable that stores the `CString` for long enough for its value to outlive the pointer.

The prolonged lifetime comes at the cost of an additional local variable. But fortunately it can be avoided - since you already have a local variable that holds the pointer, you can modify that to store the actual `CString`, and extract the pointer only when actually needed:

```
let arg_cstring = possible_arg.map(|arg| CString::new(arg).unwrap());
unsafe {
    print_in_c(arg_cstring.as_ref()
               .map(|cs| cs.as_ptr())
               .unwrap_or(std::ptr::null()));
}
```

There are several things to notice here:

- `arg_cstring` holds an `Option<CString>`, which ensures that `CString` has storage that can outlive the pointer passed to the C function;
- `Option::as_ref()` is used to prevent `arg_cstring` from being *moved* into `map`, which would again free it before the pointer was actually used;
- `Option::map()` is used as an alternative to pattern matching when you want to express "do something with `Option` if `Some`, otherwise just leave it as `None`".
- The pattern `x.as_ref().map(|x| x.as_ptr().unwrap_or(null())` can and probably should be moved into a utility function if it is used more than once in the program. Be careful that the function takes reference to `Option` to avoid a move.